# Assigning a string value to a string variable in c++

Tags: c++, string

This code is part of a larger program, and I am still new to coding, so I may be wrong, but when I execute shouldn't the shapes name display on the screen after radius and height? It currently says triangle even if I input 2 for square.

```
cout << "Please enter your choice of shape from the following menu: \n\n"
        << "1. triangle\n"
        << "2. square\n"
    cin >> choice;    

if (choice = 1)
    shape = "triangle" ;
else if (choice = 2)
    shape = "square";

cout << "Enter the side of the " << shape << ": ? ";
cin >> side;
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator. Use `==` to check for equality. Turn on compiler warnings to catch this. (For example, if you’re using g++, adding `-Wall` will warn you when you accidentally use `=`. Full example: `g++ -std=c++14 -Wall someprogram.cpp -o someprogram`.)

Comment: Radius and height?

Answer (score 1):

`choice==1` Otherwise you are assigning it. You should use the equality check.

```
if (choice == 1)
    shape = "triangle" ;
else if (choice == 2)
    shape = "square";
```